# Cannot read property 'credential' of undefined Facebook Firebase and React-Native

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, react-native

I am trying to implement a Facebook login using **FBSDK** and **Firebase** with **RNFirebase**.

On iOS everything works but on Android I have the error on the title:

```
"Cannot read property 'credential' of undefined"
```

This is the function I use:

```
export const logintoFB = () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then((result) => {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          return Promise.reject(new Error('The user cancelled the request'));        }

        // Retrieve the access token
        return AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        // Create a new Firebase credential with the token
        console.log(data);
        const credential = firebase.auth().FacebookAuthProvider.credential(data.accessToken)

        // Login with the credential
        console.log(credential);
        return firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);
      })
      .then((user) => {
        dispatch({type: types.LOGIN_STANDARD, credential: user});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const { code, message } = error;
        dispatch({type: types.LOGIN_STANDARD_FAILURE, ex: error});
      });
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there anything else that could be shared to make this more clearer.

Edit: finally that does not work on iOS too. I was just not connected to Facebook this is why I did not get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the problem: in the line `return firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);`
There are no parenthesis after the auth for Facebook login !

Comment: I was super confused with what @Kiki meant, but it should be- ```auth.FacebookAuthProvider``` I was struggling this migrating from firebase to RNFirebase so hopefully this helps someone